# Загруженный файл APK подписан сертификатом, отличающемся от указанного вами

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

При обновлении прилодения в google play выскочила ошибка

```
Сбой при загрузке
Загруженный файл APK подписан сертификатом, отличающемся от указанного вами. Цифровой отпечаток вашего сертификата:
[ SHA1: ... ]
, цифровой отпечаток сертификата электронной подписи APK-файла:
[ SHA1: ... ]
```

Но я не мог подписать приложение не том ключом так как иного просто нет...

Между последней загрузкой и этой моей попыткой прошло около недели, за это время успела обновиться СТУДИЯ, но я не могу пинять на нее...

В первую очередь я надеюсь что задав вопрос сам пойму что не так делаю, но если ущу не удалил - значит не додумался...

Comment: Вы ключ сами создавали и им подписывали .apk? Подозреваю, что первую версию вы подписывали дебаг ключом.

Comment: Suvitruf -> сам создавал, как обычно, generate signed bundle or apk -> create new... Я выпустил с десяток версий уже, но проблема пришла именно сейчас...

Comment: Ключом вы каким подписываете? Ключ генерили? https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key

Comment: Suvitruf -> все точно как в посте, на первом экране APP, потом создать новый, вбил данные, отметил release, и галочками V1, V2 -> finish,
потом просто подписывал по сохраненному псевдониму и паролю... Пароль верный потому что если поменять то не пустит в выбор ключа.

Comment: Недавно было такое - не мог выгрузить обновление. Вводил всё верно, а подпись не та. На enSO (погуглите, может ваш вариант) рекомендовали танцы с бубном. В итоге оказалось, что студия на пароле сама переключала  шрифт на русский. Ввел его в другом окне, скопировал в поле пароль и всё заработало. Мораль: думаю дело в пароле от ключа)

Comment: Jarvis_J -> Этот вариант первым исключил)

Comment: Я тоже исключил его первым)

Comment: Быто у меня не давно, что я тоже не мог загрузить apk в play console. В терминали студии я прописал **gradlew assembleRelease** дождался завершения закачки. Потом удалили папку куда сохоаняется apk. И с генерировал фвйл по новой.

Answer (score 2):

В общем создал новый проект, скопировал в него исходники, и подписал старым ключом. Все.

Comment: Ответь как ответ, хоть это и костыль

Comment: Я не нашел другого решения, мне кажется что где-то что-то кешируется не так как нужно в студии...
Кстати можно решить простым переименованием корневой директории, и открытия проекта заново.

Comment: @АндрейШпилевой как подписать старым ключом новый проект?)