# Как изменить разрешения приложения в Unity

Tags: android, google-play, unity3d-android, apk, google-play-console

Всем привет, в общем я наконец-то дошёл до публикации игры в Google Play, но вот почему то когда загружаю apk в версию выпуска то у меня вылетает вот такая ошибка:
`Для разрешений, которые применяются в вашем APK-файле или наборе Android App Bundle (например, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), необходимо добавить политику конфиденциальности. Подробнее…` я так понял дело в разрешениях приложения, есть ли какие-либо варианты это исправить?
P.S. я заново скомпилировал игру, и на этот раз к той ошибке вылетает ещё 2 вот текст:`Загруженный APK-файл подписан сертификатом, отличающимся от указанного вами. Цифровой отпечаток выбранного сертификата: SHA1: 82:09... , цифровой отпечаток подписи текущего APK-файла: SHA1: 99:38...`
Что мне делать с этим?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот, чтот нашёл:

- [Первая ошибка](https://askdev.ru/q/preduprezhdeniya-vash-apk-ispolzuet-razresheniya-kotorye-trebuyut-politiki-konfidencialnosti-android-razreshenie-chitat-sostoyanie-telefona-55691/);
- [Вторая ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/945675/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-apk-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) (я думаю, что в Unity тоже можно создать новый проект и перетащить в него исходники старого, после чего ошибка должна исчезнуть);
- [Как изменить разрешения приложения в Unity](https://dentnt.trmw.ru/14501-unity-android-manifest-permission/).